# Zend Debugger using Solaris

Tags: debugging, solaris, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I'm trying to setup debugging for PHP applications using the following environment:

-Clients: Windows XP, Zend Studio 7, Firefox+Zend Studio Toolbar

-Server: Solaris 5.10 32Bits, Apache 2.2.8, PHP 5.2.5

I'd like to use the Zend Debugger because of its easy integration into Zend Studio, and the profiling abilities; Although I'm aware of the XDebug alternative.

The problem: I can't seem to find the newest version of the Zend Debugger library for Solaris. I tried with an older version of the library, unfortunately Zend Studio spits out this message:

```
Error while communicating with the debugger.
Possible causes:
1. The Zend Debugger was not properly installed.
2. You are not using the latest Zend Debugger.
3. You are not using the latest version of the Zend Toolbar.
```

**Is there anywhere I could get the source/library for the latest Zend Debugger on Solaris?**

Answer (score 0):

The Zend debugger is a commercial binary-only product by Zend Technologies. If they don't provide it complain to their support.